# pig merge lists without key

Tags: merge, apache-pig

In Apache Pig 0.15, I have two simple lists (WITHOUT id/primary key, etc.) that I want to merge together to create one list of tuples with two columns. Example:

```
Names
-----
Peter
John
Anne

Ages
-----
45
23
44
```

I want to end up with:

```
Names  Age
---------------
Peter  45
John   23
Anne   44
```

I know I can use RANK on both lists and then JOIN, but that looks way too costly as I have millions of entries in these lists. I kind of want to do a JOIN with "merge" without having a join parameter...

Any idea about how to do this efficiently in Apache Pig?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about the mapping between Age and Name then you can try cross-join between two relations. Post Cross join group by names and retain anyone out of it. However IMO, this may be more costlier ( rather resource intensive) than the RANK approach you mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks you for your feedback, Amit. 
I ended up doing a simple RANK on both lists and joining them by RANK id. It works but is not terribly efficient.